# Passing instance variables to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I make a API call in my controller which returns a list of records, and I set the reponse equal to instance variables which I call in my view.

My Controller:

```
@products = Product.find(:all)
    @products.each do |product|
        url          = URI.parse("url{product.id}")
        @response1      = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body)
        puts @response1
        @title          = @response1["ProductName"]
        @url            = @response1["ProductUrl"]
    end
```

My view:

```
<div class= "title"><small><b><%= link_to truncate( @title, :length =>30), :target => '_blank' %></b></small></div>
```

This displays just one of the responses received. How do I display all responses received in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning @response1 and all the other variables on each iteration of @products.each , so it has a value of the last product. You must do such cycle inside your view during the output.

Like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% @response1 = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("url{product.id}")).body) %>
  <div class= "title">
    <small>
      <b>
        <%= link_to truncate( @response1["ProductName"], :length =>30), @response1["ProductUrl"], :target => '_blank' %>
      </b>
    </small>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of iterating over the responses in the controller you could do it directly in the view.

However, it would be better to assemble an array in the controller and iterate over that in the view, so you avoid giving the view too much responsibility, like:

```
@products = Product.find(:all)
@products_with_Responses = @products.map do |product|
  url = URI.parse("url{product.id}")      
  response = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body) 
  {:title          => response["ProductName"],
   :url            => response["ProductUrl"]}
end
```

Comment: So would I have to make the API call in my view also?

Comment: Not also, but instead - remove the calls from the controller and put them inside the view.